# Correctly insert a content slot (placeholder) into email template

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, html

I am building my own email template and wanted to add a few empty Content Block placeholders so that the users can later easily drag and drop content.
I am facing two problems when I am reusing the code that is used in the Salesforce templates:

1. It sometimes breaks the whole email template, things go randomly
   missing or are relocated
2. Even if I manage to insert the Content
   Block placeholder and I later put some content in there in the
   email, some of them are displayed correctly, and some of them
   disappear completely during Subscriber Preview

This is what I use, I tried both with and without the data-key:

```
    <!--slot start -->
    <div data-type="slot" data-key="pt7lnaathjqvxndvyt7rv0a4i" data-label="Drop blocks or content here">
    </div>
    <!--slot end-->
```

Can you please let me know what is the correct way to insert Content Block placeholders?

Comment: Easiest thing to do is use a out of the box template and strip out what you don't need.